# What's the word for laughing in a sad situation?

Tags: word-choice

I don't know if it's heartless,but when I'm in a situation that is really sad(like a funeral) I always have this urge to laugh.Of course I try not to burst out in laughter but I guess it's how I cope with these things.

Is there a word that can describe this?I don't mind if it would be used for the urge,the behaviour,the feeling.I'm just really interested how to express this kind of thing without having to say that I really,really have to laugh.

Comment: One common phrase is "*If I didn't laugh, I would cry*", but I'm not sure it's completely applicable to the emotion you're describing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Nervous-laughter** should be a appropriate word. And in a novel I read a word **painful-dimples**, It sounds compatible too. But `painful-dimples` kind of word is not heard or seen usually.

Answer (score 3):

The psychological term is "inappropriate affect".  Not to make you nervous... but, it can be an indicator of pathology.

Comment: Inappropriate affect means to experience an inappropriate feeling. The OP said nothing about any feeling experienced.

Comment: Nope. Inappropriate affect is not about the "feeling"- which may not be easily interpreted or described. It's about the physical "response" to the circumstances not being consistent with what is considered usual or "normal"

Comment: Laughter is one of a very wide range of normal grief-responses, e.g. see http://www.tc.columbia.edu/news.htm?articleId=2933 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grief#Reactions http://psycnet.apa.org/?&fa=main.doiLanding&doi=10.1037/0003-066X.59.1.20

Comment: You **might** want to explain the technical jargon used here. For example, most people know *affect* as a verb, not a noun; and *pathology* is best known as the **science** of cause/effect of disease, rather than "mental or social abnormality or malfunction" (Oxford).

Comment: I appreciate your answer.Although it seems appropriate,I'm not sure if I want to describe my actions with technical jargon,especially if it hints that I might be a psychopath...*crazy laughter*

Comment: "Affect"(noun)-from Merriam Webster: a set of observable manifestations of a subjectively experienced emotion. "Pathology" seems to be acceptable as a means of describing something abnormal, within the confines of this example - according to my research.

Comment: @oldbag I see affect defined in both ways: The subjective experience of an emotion and/or its observable expression. Since the OP describes subjective experiences, then your answer misses the mark using your own definition, though your suggestion certainly lives in the neighborhood of what she describes.

Comment: "4. Psychology. feeling or emotion. 5. Psychiatry. an expressed or observed emotional response:
Restricted, flat, or blunted affect may be a symptom of mental illness, especially schizophrenia...." http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/affect

Answer (score 1):

I'd describe that as a fit of [hysterical](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hysterical) laughter :

Hysterical:

> - uncontrollably emotional.
> - irrational from fear, emotion, or an emotional shock.

( from dictionary.reference.com)

Comment: These descriptions don't match the OP's reported experiences.

Answer (score 0):

Titter

to laugh nervously, often at something that you feel you should not be laughing at.

Comment: A titter has some particular qualities. The OP's description does not suggest tittering, though I do see a relationship in the idea of suppression. https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=define+titter&oq=define+titter&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l2.7425j0j4&client=ms-android-samsung&sourceid=chrome-mobile&espv=1&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Laughter is a highly complex behavior. One term for what you describe might be *nervous laughter* (if you actually laughed instead of just felt the urge to laugh). But that term is used in various ways, so as far as I know, the best way to describe it is similar to what you did in the question.