# An alternative for sadly giggling?

Tags: synonyms

Is there a word to describe a sad or an ironic giggle as if you're actually hurt but still find the situation funny in a way?

Comment: A nervous laugh? Laughing through tears like Pagliacci?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/210792/whats-the-word-for-laughing-in-a-sad-situation

Answer (score 1):

chuckled ruefully

rue·ful·ly
ˈro͞ofəlē/
adverb:
in a way that expresses sorrow or regret, especially in a wry or humorous manner.

Answer (score 0):

I can't suggest a single word for the same.
I would rather suggest "**a melancholic laugh**".
As melancholic means gloomy.